# How to convert a specific format of string to date/seconds shell script linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, date

I need to convert a string of `%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S` (e.g `18/04/25 16:04:00`) to seconds.

`date -d "18/04/25 16:04:00" "+%s"` results in invalid format, though `date -d "04/25/2018 16:04:00" "+%s"` gives correct result.

Is it possible specify the format of string (i.e. `18/04/25 16:04:00`) as I can do in `OS X`, `date -j -f '%y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S' '18/04/25 16:04:00' +'%s'`?

Comment: See http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/coreutils-4.5.4/html_chapter/coreutils_27.html for what date formats are supported by GNU date. Suggest formatting the original strings to the way suppored, rather then actually messing with the formats

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Apple Stack Exchange](http://apple.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add century at the start of your string to make it work in `gnu date`:

```
dt="18/04/25 16:04:00"
date -d "$(date '+%C')$dt" '+%s'
```

```
1524686640
```

`$(date '+%C')` will return current century i.e. `20`